# Alguma explicação para este SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$alters = " ALTER TABLE imovel
  MODIFY COLUMN ENDERECO VARCHAR(150),
  MODIFY COLUMN BAIRRO VARCHAR(150)";
$pdo->exec($alters);
```

Conforme eu vou diminuindo o valor do varchar, ele vai atualizando, mas se eu aumentar o valor do varchar não funciona mais.

Alguma explicação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode unir todos os MODIFY:

```
ALTER TABLE imovel
  MODIFY (ENDERECO VARCHAR(150),
          BAIRRO VARCHAR(150)
          );
```

*OBS: Não sei se é compativel com o MySQL o trecho acima!*

Mas, também pode remover o parâmetro "COLUMN", para o MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE imovel
  MODIFY ENDERECO VARCHAR(150),
  MODIFY BAIRRO VARCHAR(150);
```

Até onde saiba, o único que tem "`[FUNÇÃO] COLUMN nome_da_coluna`" é o `DROP`, este é "`DROP COLUMN`".

Porém, todo o resto é `MODIFY nome_da_coluna` e `ADD nome_da_coluna`, sem incluir o `COLUMN` no nome da função.